# How to add a field as a key to a hibernate update statement

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, orm

I am using postgres 9.4 and have a date range partitioned table.  The primary key on the table is `id`.  The tables is partitioned on a field called `create_date`.  We are inserting into the partitions using an insert trigger which looks at the `create_date` field and writes it into the appropriate partition.

We are using Hibernate 4.3.11 for ORM.  To update data in the table we are using the `EntityManager::merge` method.  I would like to add the `create_date` to the `WHERE` clause of the `update` SQL that Hibernate generates.

For example, right now my update looks like:

`UPDATE my_table SET col1 = $1 where id = $2`

In order to get partition pruning in my `update` statement I would like my query to look like this:

`UPDATE my_table SET col1 = $1 where id = $2 and create_date = $3`

Is there any way to accomplish this with Hibernate?

Comment: Can you share with us your code you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't really get why you need this, table partitioning should be transparent from the client perspective. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov I don't have code to show, because I can't see any way to do it.  On the `select` side I can use a query builder. (It appears I can't edit my question to add this code block above.  Sorry!

CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyTable> criteria = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(MyTable.class);
Root<MyTable> from = criteria.from(MyTable.class);
criteria.select(from);
criteria.where(
 builder.equal(from.get("id"), id),
 builder.equal(from.get("createDate"), date));
return em.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();

Comment: @galovics If you don't give the proper criteria in a query the optimizer cannot partition prune.  My table is partitioned by `date` but the primary key of the table is `id`.  If I run `select * from my_table where id = 'abc'` then postgres cannot partition prune because it has no idea which partition that ID is in.  However if I run `select * from my_table where id = 'abc' and create_date = DATE '2018-05-10'` then it only has to look at one partition.

Comment: If I check the explain plan on and update with create_date included I get a much simpler explain plan:
```Update on my_table  (cost=0.19..8.21 rows=1 width=403)
  ->  Index Scan using my_table_pkey on my_table  (cost=0.19..8.21 rows=1 width=403)
        Index Cond: (id = 'abc'::text)
        Filter: (create_date = '2018-05-10'::date)

```

If I leave off the create_date from the where clause it bumps up the cost to 313.98 and I get an index scan on all 30 partitions in my table.